# Data are not in sequence in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have use highchart.js , area chart. Data represents are hits in hours which is starting from 0 - 23. Now the problem is in sequence. Why highchart.js does show data from 0 to 23. [image]

As you can see in this chart. 10 must comes after 9.
I have already make below hours is in int using parseInt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Kindly double check, how you are populating your x-axis data.
It will get displayed based  their respective index value in array, i.e below keep 1,2 and 10 on x-axis.
xAxis: {
            categories: [1, 2, 10]
        },

While below will keep 10,1 and 2 on x-axis.

xAxis: {
            categories: [10, 1, 2]
        },
```